# Polymer and Google-Sheets component loading ALL spreadsheets

Tags: google-drive-api, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-sheets-api, firebase-polymer

I'm building a Polymer app and I'm trying to load all spreadsheets from a google drive account but am having trouble. I can bring individual spreadsheets in at a time, but is there a way to bring all in at once? The [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-sheets#property-key)(attached) say it is possible by leaving out the key but i'm not having any luck. Please find my code below. Any help would be much appreciated.
Justin

### my-dashboard.html

The below works for individual spreadsheets

```
<google-sheets
        key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        client-id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        rows="{{rows}}"
        published >
    </google-sheets>

    <my-googlesheets-element rows="{{rows}}" user="[[user]]"></my-googlesheets-element>
```

### my-googlesheets-element.html

```
<dom-module id="my-googlesheets-element">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <h1>google sheet comp here</h1>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{rows}}">
      <div id$="[[item.$key]]">
        <p>{{item.gsx$author.$t}}</p>
      </div>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-googlesheets-element",
      properties: {
        rows: {
          type: Object
        },
      },
      observers: [ 'logRows(rows.*)' ],
      logRows: function() {
        console.log('rows data', this.rows)
      },
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: The docs say that leaving out the key will return a LIST of spreadsheets, not the actual spreadsheets themselves.

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN The [`<google-sheets>.spreadsheets`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets/google-sheets#property-spreadsheets) property provides the metadata list of spreadsheets available in Google Drive. You could parse the IDs from the list and then fetch each spreadsheet.

Comment: @pinoyyid I know but leaving it out returns an error. Completely lost on this one?

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN In my tests, omitting the `key` made no difference to the value of the `spreadsheets` property. It's always populated with the metadata list. What is the error you see?